# ASP.NET MVC 2 client-side validation triggering incorrectly

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations, validation

I am using DataAnnotations to enable client-side validation in an ASP.NET MVC 2 project.  I am having an issue where my URL validation regex passes my unit test, but it fails in the actual website.

### Model

```
[RegularExpression(UrlValidation.Regex, ErrorMessage = UrlValidation.Message)]
public string Url { get; set; }

Regex = "(([\w]+:)?//)?(([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+(:([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?([\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.)+[\w]{2,4}(:[\d]+)?(/([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*(\?(&?([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?"
```

Message = "Invalid Url"

### View

```
<div class="editor-label">
    <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Url) %>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Url) %>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Url) %>
</div>
```

Result With URL = `http://www.chicagoshakes.com/main.taf?p=7,8`

[image]

### Passing Unit Test

```
[Test]
public void GetVarUrlPasses()
{
    var url = "http://www.chicagoshakes.com/main.taf?p=7,8";
    var regex = new Regex(UrlValidation.Regex);
    Assert.IsTrue(regex.IsMatch(url));
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is passing the unit test, but failing when I test the view in a browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alan Moore was basically right, the regex was junk.  I ended up using a [this regex](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls).

Also, here's the proper way to write the unit test:

```
[Test]
public void GetVarUrlPasses()
{
    var url = "http://www.chicagoshakes.com/main.taf?p=7,8";
    var attribute = new RegularExpressionAttribute(regex);
    Assert.IsTrue(regex.IsValid(url));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see several problems with that regex, but what's tripping you up is probably the comma in `p=7,8`.  Your regex doesn't match it, but `IsMatch` doesn't require it to; it's perfectly happy stopping at the `7`.  I would guess that the client-side validator is implicitly anchoring the match.  The regex should be anchored anyway; add a `^` to the beginning and `$` to the end, and you should at least get *consistent* results.  Then you can change the regex to accommodate the comma.

There's also a typo in the regex: the second `f` in `[a-fA-f\d]` should be `F`.  And, although it's not an *error* to have `\d` and `\w` in the same set of square brackets, it is redundant; `\w` matches digits as well as letters, so you can remove the `\d` (and `[\w\d]` can be reduced to `\w`).  Finally, `{2,2}` should be simply `{2}`.

Comment: Thanks.  I got the regex from regexlib.com but I thought the unit test would be sufficient to test it.  What do you mean by the "validator is implicitly anchoring the match"?  In the meantime I will work on the regex.

Comment: Most regex tools will tell you a regex "matches" a string if it describes any *part* of the string; for example, the regex `\d+` matches `ABC123XYZ`.  If you want to match only strings that contain nothing *but* digits, you have to anchor the regex: `^\d+$`.  But some tools, like Java's `matches()` method or XML Schema processors, act as if every regex were anchored at both ends, so `\d+` will match `123` but not `ABC123XYZ`.  Validators usually have to account for the whole string, so it's not unreasonable to expect them to behave that way too.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's passing the unit test, the problem may be in your controller or model. Is `Url` ever directly accessed?

Comment: The model is posted above, do you see a problem in it?  I doubt it's the controller since this is client-side validation, not server-side.